# How can I get feedback on a business idea for providing English language support for specific projects?

Tags: professionalism, communication, human-resources, startup, research

I have an idea for a business providing non-native English professionals with collaborative, real-time language support for specific projects, such as business reports. This support would sit at the interface of editing, mentoring, and language training.

It would be aimed at companies who employ, or periodically work with, high-value non-native English speaking professionals lacking confidence in formal English communication. The idea is to take the stress out of the language aspect of the project and allow them to concentrate on their expertise.

Ideally, I would like to survey HR and Training & Development managers to get their feedback and ideas on refining the concept. What would be the best way of contacting them and persuading them to either complete a questionnaire or engage in an informal discovery call?

Comment: Few people have patience for cold calling - most companies, I can only guess, have zero patience

Comment: No, I hate cold calling too!

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to sell such a concept. Ideally you actually have a viable service before you start cold-contacting people.

This would mean having suitably qualified/certified people to do the work in specific languages. Some govts retain similar businesses to help interact with their consultants, but private industry seems less likely to. A least that's how it plays out here. Except here there is no way to get your foot in without contacts in govt, it's a lucrative revenue stream.

If you target govt work you need paperwork, qualifications/certification and probably existing contacts within the govt.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful reply. Can you suggest why private industry is less likely to opt for this type of support?

Comment: Expense and control

Answer (score 0):

A few points that I think you should note:

It is very difficult to get someone's attention for a CONCEPT. Try YOU to execute this idea. Offer this service as a freelancer for a while and use the money to gradually team up with some Dev's and launch a online service. And yes, this can take some time.

Also, Expertise and Methods. You need know-how for this service. You need to know your target audience and who you are going to hire. You need to know how you will screen your collaborators and so on. Some companies take tests whose answers are wide open on some websites, others require some level of proficiency based on a certificate such as the TOEIC, Cambridge or EF SET (C1 Advanced, for example).

A project that has been active for some time, that has a **target** and is **profitable** is more interesting. If you get there, *you might not even want to sell anymore*.